# Can we use class on a <style> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, styles

The thing is for **js purpose** I want a particular `<style>` tag to be removed from my document on an event. So for that, within my knowledge, I have added a class for it and removed on my event, eg:

```
<style class="custome_for_remove">
  .selected_par>td,
  .footer-tr>td {
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell!important
  }.....
</style>


<script>
function customeRemove() {
  $('.custome_for_remove').remove()
}
</script>
```

My concern is this HTML standard, is this a proper method.? I couldn't find any questions or answer related to this.

Comment: `class` is a [global attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes) and therefore available on any element. Now that's been said, what you're doing is indeed a bit odd. Usually you'd simply want to add/remove classes to/from actual elements if you want to change what rules apply to them. But what you're doing is technically OK.

Comment: Just wrap you styles in common parent class and remove that SIMPLE. above syntax is invalid `<style>` didn't pick class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! This totally works and it also seems to be valid syntax. Here's a little demonstration. According to https://validator.w3.org/ having a class in your style tag is considered valid html (you can also use an id if you want).

```js
$("#test").click(() => {
  $(".customClass").remove();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style class="customClass">
  p {
    color: red;
  }
</style>

<p>
  Test
</p>
<button id="test">
remove
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code. It removes CSS perfectly.

```js
function removeJs(){
   $(".custome_for_remove").remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<style class="custome_for_remove">
  p {
    color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
</style>

<p onclick="removeJs()">
  Click here!
</p>
```